# Why is `Series.apply` applied to set of all categories and not just the current slice?

Tags: python, pandas, apply, categories, series

In the case of a categorical series `Series.apply` does not only apply its parameter `func` to the entries in the series in a selected slice, but to all categories in `Series.cat.catgeories`. Why? That seems inefficient and unnecessary. When I want to apply `apply` many times to small subsections of a column, I do not want to run `func` on *all* the values in `Series.cat.catgeories` every single time I merley want to run it on the entries of my current subsection of the column.

---

## Example

I have a data set of feature vectors of text data in form of a pandas.DataFrame. One column contains words as a categorical pandas.Series. I want to map a word2vec lookup over the series.

I initialize my data structures as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

wordvectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('data/wordvectors', binary=True)
store = pd.HDFStore('data/data.h5')
data = store.entries_categorized
```

I select a slice and isolate one of the word columns for demonstration:

```
slice = data.iloc[:4]
words = slice['token-word']
```

This is how `words` looks and its type:

```
0     Stunden
1     stunden
2    fertigen
3    Fertigen
Name: token-word, dtype: category
Categories (1226, object): [Stunden, stunden, fertigen, Fertigen, ..., stressen, Stressen, Pediküren, pediküren]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

As you can see there are 4 words in this 4 row long slice of that column.

Now I want to convert all entries in `words` like so

```
words = words.apply(func=lambda x : wordvectors[x])
```

But apparently, `apply` also applies `func` on the set of categories:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3d9458fde26d> in <module>()
      3 print(words)
      4 print(type(words))
----> 5 words = words.apply(func=lambda x : wordvectors[x])

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3189             # row-wise access
   3190             if is_extension_type(self.dtype):
-> 3191                 mapped = self._values.map(f)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/categorical.py in map(self, mapper)
   1189         Index(['first', 'second', nan], dtype='object')
   1190         """
-> 1191         new_categories = self.categories.map(mapper)
   1192         try:
   1193             return self.from_codes(self._codes.copy(),

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in map(self, mapper, na_action)
   3447         from .multi import MultiIndex
   3448         new_values = super(Index, self)._map_values(
-> 3449             mapper, na_action=na_action)
   3450 
   3451         attributes = self._get_attributes_dict()

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1002 
   1003         # mapper is a function
-> 1004         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1005 
   1006         return new_values

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-20-3d9458fde26d> in <lambda>(x)
      3 print(words)
      4 print(type(words))
----> 5 words = words.apply(func=lambda x : wordvectors[x])

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in __getitem__(self, entities)
    334         if isinstance(entities, string_types):
    335             # allow calls like trained_model['office'], as a shorthand for trained_model[['office']]
--> 336             return self.get_vector(entities)
    337 
    338         return vstack([self.get_vector(entity) for entity in entities])

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in get_vector(self, word)
    452 
    453     def get_vector(self, word):
--> 454         return self.word_vec(word)
    455 
    456     def words_closer_than(self, w1, w2):

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in word_vec(self, word, use_norm)
    449             return result
    450         else:
--> 451             raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
    452 
    453     def get_vector(self, word):

KeyError: "word 'mengen' not in vocabulary"
```

'mengen' is in the set of categories. But it is *not* in the current slice of the column. Hence `apply` is run not only on the 4-row subsection, but all values in `Series.cat.catgeories`.

Comment: Applying `astype('object')` to the categorical column at least seems to solve the problem.